# Learning Swift in Xcode 6.1

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm currently learning Swift from a tutorial video using Xcode 6.0. The code was given to me to edit as a read through, However, the code seems to be outdated already. I'm getting syntax errors for example this line:

```
var sceneData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfMapFiled(path!, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)
```

> // Error: extra argument 'options' in call

Keep in mind that I'm very new to programming and swift is the first language I plan on learning how to write from scratch. I've looked up the differences between 6.0 and 6.1 and couldn't find a great description of all of the changes.

This is the link to the tutorial I'm following.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q6kTw_cK3zY

Any help with this code/learning swift/expectations on learning the syntax would be very helpful.

First post on Stackoverflow,

Thanks,

Joey

Comment: Is the 'd' in 'dataWithContentsOfMapFiled' a typo? There should be no 'd' at the end, i.e. `dataWithContentsOfMapFile`

Comment: the error after your correction is 'NSData.Type' does not have a member named 'dataWithContentsOfMapFile'

Comment: Yes, this is because, it should be `dataWithContentsOfMappedFile`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two typos in your code, specifically `dataWithContentsOfMapFiled` should be `dataWithContentsOfMappedFile`. However, this is also marked as deprecated (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithContentsOfMappedFile:)) and does not provide an argument `options:`. Therefore, you would have to replace it by e.g. `dataWithContentsOfFile:options:error:` (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithContentsOfFile:options:error:)).

Personally, I think it would be the best, if you have a look into the documentation and decide which method fits best for what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me

```
var sceneData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)
```